# Trying to perform 2 php inserts on the same database connection

Tags: php, mysql

Full disclosure, I am a php noob my background is in .NET dev

So I have the following php code:

```
if ($conn->query($insert_listing) === TRUE) {
    $listing_id = $conn->insert_id;
} 
else {
    echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
}
```

then I build my second query and then I have the following code:

```
if ($conn->multi_query($insert_times) === TRUE) {
    echo = "times inserted";
} 
else {
    echo = "Error: " . $conn->error;
}
```

$conn is the variable holding my database connection and I know the connection is fine because the first bit of code runs fine if the second is commented out. I also know that the queries held in $insert_listing and $insert_times are correct as I have echoed them and run them in my database engine. When I try and load my page I get a 500 server error.

As a side note is there a way I can get the actual 500 error message so I have a better idea of where to look to troubleshoot the issue?

EDIT: Problem solved! Found the error log, lead me to the problem, I was accidentally assigning to echo in the second code fragment!

Comment: If you're just starting to learn now, learn it right, from the start. http://php.net/pdo

Comment: The error is probably in the PHP log - where that is depends on your system; on mine its in /var/log/php5/php5.log. The error_log setting in php.ini should point to it. It could also be logging to syslog so check there too.

Comment: Show the content of `$insert_times`

Comment: @RayO'Donnell Thank you! I found the error log! Lead me straight to the problem! I was assigning to echo by mistake in the second code fragment, problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
echo = "times inserted";
```

You cannot assign to `echo`, I guess you meant:

```
echo "times inserted";
```

Comment: Exactly that, need to be more careful when I copy and paste code to re-purpose it!